# Part window static, part window dynamic, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a window which has a static part that is always the same, and a dynamic part which changes depending on buttons from the static part.

I you look at my drawing, the green area is the static part which i want to always be the same. The black boxes is meant to be buttons, to change the red part.
For example, the 4 black buttons could be: Customer overview, Ticket overview, Product overview and so on. So if i click the Customer overview button, the red area should ofcourse update to show customer overview.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

[image: Wanted design]

Comment: Is there any reason why `TabControl` isn't suitable?

Comment: Not at all.. Im just brand new to wpf.. If been searching around, but i dont think i've managed to find the right search keywords...
Would you suggest that?

Comment: It really depends on your applications navigation mode. If you wanted a tabbed multipled document interface (all the pages are avaliable to navigate between freely), then it makes sense. However, if you want a page-based application (like a website) then you will need to construct something more elaborate using buttons and swapping user controls in and out of a `ContentControl` in the red area.